# Aliased arguments in strtol

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier, strtol

Here is how `strtol` has to be declared according to `§ 7.22.1.4` from C11 (n1570):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long int strtol (const char *restrict nptr,
                 char **restrict endptr,
                 int base);
```

As far as I know, the `restrict` keyword means that the object referenced by the lvalue `*nptr` will be accessed only with it or a value directly derived from it.

However, a lot of programmers, and even experienced ones, use `strtol` in the following way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

strtol (p, &p, 10);
```

In that case, `**endptr == **&p == *p == *nptr`, and the behavior is undefined. Is it right?

Comment: A while ago I wrote a blog post on the topic that `restrict` is frustrating as an element of specification because it implicitly refers to the implementation. If a `strtol()` implementation accesses both `**endptr` and `*nptr` then it is undefined to pass `p` and `&p` to it. If it doesn't, then it is not undefined to pass these arguments. The specification implied by `restrict` only makes sense with respect to the very implementation that should be hidden by the specification. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/08/02/restrict-not-modular

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Nothing is accessed via `**endptr` in `strtol`. Only `*endptr`, a completely separate object, is accessed.